# When unreferenced @Singleton beans are destroyed?

Tags: java, scope, cdi

I have a Java SE application with CDI/Weld (started with `org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain`).

I'm injecting a `@Singleton` bean into another bean:

```
public class CdiMain {

    @Inject
    private MySingleton mySingleton;

    public void onStart(@Observes ContainerInitialized event) {
        mySingleton.printHello();
        mySingleton = null;

        // other long running stuff
    }
}
```

I don't need the singleton bean after the `printHello` method. When will it be destroyed?

Comment: I believe it's when you shutdown your container.

Comment: If your `CdiMain` bean object reference is not referenced by any mean, both `CdiMain` and `MySingleton` will be eligible to be freed by GC.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Are you sure that CDI won't have a reference for its bean which prevents GC to free `mySingleton` instance?

Comment: @jt8 since it is a `@Singleton`, then CDI will maintain the reference until the application is undeployed. But this doesn't mean that the reference of `CdiMain` will be kept alive.

Comment: They're like GMOs -- Frankenbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Singleton.html) it is unclear if a `@Singleton` bean will be destroyed at some specific point.
I wouldn't rely on that. For instance during `Weld.shutdown()` `@PreDestroy` method is not called on a `@Singleton`.

Use `@ApplicationScoped` bean instead, it's functionally the same (except that it's proxied), also available in Java SE and will be 'destroyed' when the application context ends.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just for the record: Using Weld in Java SE calls the `@PreDestory` method on `@Signleton`s.

Comment: The [full doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-intro007.htm#JEETT01089) is more complete about it: it's destroyed at the end of its lifecycle (which in turn is the end of the container's lifecycle).